# Fix an error in PHP QBWC Dev Kit

Tags: qbwc

I am trying to export from `QB` to `MySQL` some tables. This particular program was running well, but I am getting the following error:20170719.19:19:48 UTC:-

> QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""
>   20170719.19:19:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""
>   20170719.19:19:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : Received from receiveResponseXML() following parameters:
>   20170719.19:19:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : more="-1">
>   20170719.19:19:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_getLastError() : *** Calling getLastError() with following parameter:
>   20170719.19:19:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_getLastError() : wcTicket="e047c407-23a3-d2e4-7541-f99e1bc8c359"
>   20170719.19:19:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_getLastError() : Received from getLastError() following parameter:
>   20170719.19:19:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_getLastError() : errorMsg="3391: The iteratorID "{14d06ce8-b17d-440f-b1c1-9b67610ada7c}" is not valid."
>   20170719.19:19:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_getLastError() : Received error from application: 3391: The iteratorID "{14d06ce8-b17d-440f-b1c1-9b67610ada7c}" is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to see what is going on.

A couple of possibilities: 
1. You have finished reading all the data and the iterator is no longer valid. 
2. IteratorID is only good for a single session and you kept the id from a previous session.